# Remote Hardware sharing

Tags: remote-desktop

Is there some way to connect to other machine or other PC of larger hardware capabilities (Processor, RAM, ..)at work or colleague's; for my work to be rendered or processed on, remotely, then saved at my PC normally ?

this is like sharing remote hardware resources ?

I am new to ubuntu, using ubuntu DeskTop 14.04 and I am NOT an IT expert at all, so I'd appreciate any help :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this tutorial may be a bit outdated but it explains the concept well, however, may not be what you are looking for http://techtinkering.com/2009/12/02/setting-up-a-beowulf-cluster-using-open-mpi-on-linux/